# Load Data from API Need to Use a Parameter Which is from a Calculated Model

Tags: google-app-maker

Hi I am using App Maker to build the application that would load the data from Google Team Drive. I was able to get the Team Drive ID from Team Drive API and saved in the calculated model.

Then I want to create another page which can show the folder list in a selected team drive by using the same method. However, the function need to pass a drive Id. I don't know how to connect these two together. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define parameter within you Client Model's datasource:

[image]

After that you can access it on the client and bind it to some widget or set it by script:

```js
// binding
@datasources.FolderList.query.parameters.DriveId

// Client script
app.datasources.FolderList.query.parameters.DriveId = 'some value';
```